# Rendering into QGLWidget that runs at a different thread than main

Tags: multithreading, qt, user-interface, opengl, qglwidget

I managed to start a QApplication at a different thread than main and run my QGLWidget there, however, when ever I try to execute an opengl command in my main thread I get gl invalid operation error. I suspect if it is about having gl context in a different thread but couldn't find a way to get the context of QGLWidget and set as current in main thread as my QGLWidget runs on a different thread .

Any suggestions?

note:I really need to have seperae threat for GUI and opengl computations.

Answer (score 0):

You should have QApplication in main thread (GUI in main thread) and all computations you can move to other threads. But not GUI, only main thread for GUI (QApplication).

Comment: But then this time context will remain in the main thread but the computations will be on other thread, How will the openGl state machine work like that?